# How to have exactly ">>>" in a report

Tags: characters, ligatures

In my latex article, I do have to use the 3 following chars >>> .

However after compiling my latex code, the displayed content is far from being >>>, but gives two chars instead : »> . How can I solve this issue ?

Same question regarding <<<, which gives «< .

My used package :

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[left=3cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{ucs}
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: What about `\ggg` and `\lll` from `amssymb` package?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `>>` becomes a ligature ». You can break it by braces, in various ways, such as by

```
>{>}>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I didn't know about these ligatures.

Answer (score 4):

Since you are using the `babel` package you also can use

```
>"|>"|>
```

(meaning *disable ligatures at this point*)

The `microtype` package offers a more convenient solution if you use `>>>` very often:

```
\DisableLigatures[>]{encoding = T1}
```

(see package documentation under *8 Disabling ligatures*, not tested)